# Javascript : Image not downloading anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code bellow used to download an image while adding a custom name to it. I kinda forgot about it for some time and wanted to retry the download and it doesn't work anymore. Did I messed up anything here ?

```
let imageInit =
  'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
let image = imageInit.replace('350x250', '200x200');
if (!image) {
  return;
}

var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
  request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

const generatedName = uuidv4();
const finalName = generatedName.concat('.png');

download(image, finalName, function () {
  console.log('done');
});
```

Edit : This is weird. When trying with this link `'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'` it downloads, but doesn't work with any other link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I fill in the appropriate modules that you're using, this code here works just fine for me in node v16.13.2:

```
const request = require('request');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const fs = require('fs');

let imageInit = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
let image = imageInit.replace('350x250', '200x200');
if (!image) {
    return;
}

var download = function(uri, filename, callback) {
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

const generatedName = uuidv4();
const finalName = generatedName.concat('.png');
console.log(finalName);

download(image, finalName, function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Is there something different in your whole code?  Or does this specific code not work for you?

Things you can examine in your own code:

1. Add error handling to both `request()` stream and to the writeStream to log any errors.
2. Try to load the `https://via.placeholder.com/200x200` URL into your own browser to just see if that works.
3. Tell us more about "doesn't work anymore" actually means.  What do you observe?  What do you see in the logs?  Where does it stop executing?

Here's a version of the code with a lot more error handling/logging:

```
const request = require('request');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const fs = require('fs');

let imageInit = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
let image = imageInit.replace('350x250', '200x200');
if (!image) {
    return;
}

var download = function(uri, filename, callback) {
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

        let wStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename).on('error', err => { console.log(err); });
        let rStream = request(uri).on('error', err => { console.log(err); });
        rStream.pipe(wStream).on('close', () => callback(null));
    });
};

const generatedName = uuidv4();
const finalName = generatedName.concat('.png');
console.log(finalName);

download(image, finalName, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('finished with error');
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

---

Please note that the `request()` module has been deprecated so really shouldn't be used in new code going forward.  A good set of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

Comment: 1. I don't know how to exactly do so. 2. The URL in my browser works perfectly. 3. As I mentioned in my edit, only the 'google url' link is working but is downloading a corrupt image. Any other link just do not download or do anything. The thing is it used to download just fine since one month ago. And since you are mentioning a possible deprecation of the module I think it maybe that too. But then again you are saying that's working good for you so I really don't know..

Comment: @AlyaKra - When you say does not download or do anything, you need to add error handling and find out where things are going wrong.  Your code has NO error handling at all so if there was an error, you wouldn't log it or see it.  Add error handling.

Comment: @AlyaKra - See what I added to my answer for error handling.

Comment: I tried it in a new file and apparently it's working just fine. I think it may be an interference with my old code somewhere as I'm calling a lot of async functions there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found the source of the problem; I had `process.exit(1);` in the end of my code.

This was added in order to end the execution of the whole code once everything is finished, but apparently with this the image is not downloaded too. Removing it fixed the issue in addition of the snippet provided by @jfriend00.